# Sprockets::FileNotFound in Ruby Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Ruby -v 2.2.1 and Rails version 4.2.4 with gems haml, simple_form, and bootstrap-sass indicated below. I consistently get the following error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Static_page#index
```

The error also indicates that it could not find my file in javascript/application, more specifically this is what I have app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-sprockets
```

In addition, I have these included as well in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I also have the following included in my application.css.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

And here are the gem files I am using:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.7'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

gem 'spring'
end
```

I have already conducted a **bundle install** and **restarted my rails sever** several times to try to troubleshoot.

Why does this error keep occurring and might there be some kind of incompatibility with my gems' versions?  Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Bower? Otherwise you should only need //= require bootstrap or bootstrap-sprockets depending on your needs. See [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/README.md#a-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: do you have staticpage#index ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error simply states that it cannot find the JS file which has been called in `application.js`.

---

According to the [docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails), you need to have the following in your `JS` pipeline to get it working:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Referencing `bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-sprockets` seems to violate that pattern (remember, `asset_path` acts like a [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) env var -- you can reference individual files *without* the relative path).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened after upgrading to rails 7, and was because rails 7 doesn't come with Sprockets.

I fixed by adding sprockets and everything worked:

```rb
# Gemfile
gem "sprockets-rails"
```

More info [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#sprockets-is-now-an-optional-dependency)